# GroupBy with list of keys -- Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, optimization, group-by

I'm micro-optimising some code as a challenge.

I have a list of objects with a list of keys in each of them.
What's the most efficient way of grouping them by key, with each object being in every group of which it has a key.

This is what I have, but I have a feeling it can be improved.
I have many objects (100k+), each has ~2 keys, and there's less than 50 possible keys.
I've tried parallelising the list with `listOfObjs.par`, but there doesn't seem to be much of an improvement overall.

```
case class Obj(value: Option[Int], key: Option[List[String]])

listOfObjs
  .filter(x => x.key.isDefined && x.value.isDefined)
  .flatMap(x => x.key.get.map((_, x.value.get)))
  .groupBy(_._1)
```

Comment: Your result is `Map[String,List[(String, Int)]]` where `String` represents duplicate data, i.e. the `Map` key is always the same as the 1st element of the tuple. Is this duplication necessary? Why not `Map[String,List[Int]]`?

Comment: what about `listOfObjs.collect{ case Obj(Some(v), Some(k)) => k.map((_, v)) }.flatten.groupBy(_._1)`

Comment: @jwvh that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve with the groupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many object, the logical next step would be to distribute the work by using a MapReduce framework. At the end of the day you still need to go over every single object to determine the group it belongs in and your worst case will be bottlenecked by that.

The best you can do here is to replace these 3 operations by a `fold` so you only iterate through the collection once.

Edit: Updated the order based on Luis' recommendation in the comments

```
listOfObj.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[Int]]){ (acc, obj) =>
  (obj.key, obj.value) match { 
    case (Some(k), Some(v)) => 
      k.foldLeft(acc)((a, ky) => a + (ky -> {v +: a.getOrElse(ky, List.empty)}))))
    case _ => acc
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to prepend to the `List` and then reverse at the end. - Also, it is usually recommended to call the `empty` factory methods instead of an empty `apply`

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Def. haven't looked into the benchmarks that close. Updated based on your recommendations

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression you are looking for a fast alternative; thus a little bit of encapsulated mutability can help.
So, what about something like this:

```scala
def groupObjectsByKey(objects: List[Obj]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  val iter =
    objects.iterator.flatMap {
      case Obj(Some(value), Some(keys)) =>
        keys.iterator.map(key => key -> value)
      
      case _ =>
        Iterator.empty[(String, Int)]
    }

  val m =
    mutable
      .Map
      .empty[String, mutable.Builder[Int, List[Int]]
  
  iter.foreach {
    case (k, v) =>
      m.get(key = k) match {
        case Some(builder) =>
          builder.addOne(v)
          
        case None =>
          m.update(key = k, value = List.newBuilder[Int].addOne(v))
      }
  }
  
  immutable
    .Map
    .mapFactory[String, List[Int]]
    .fromSpecific(m.view.mapValues(_.result()))
}
```

Or if you don't care about the order of the elements of each group we can simplify and speed up the code a lot:

```scala
def groupObjectsByKey(objects: List[Obj]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  val iter = objects.iterator.flatMap {
    case Obj(Some(value), Some(keys)) =>
      keys.iterator.map(key => key -> value)
    
    case _ =>
      Iterator.empty[(String, Int)]
  }

  val m = mutable.Map.empty[String, List[Int]]
  
  iter.foreach {
    case (k, v) =>
      m.updateWith(key = k) match {
        case Some(list) =>
          Some(v :: list)
          
        case None =>
          Some(v :: Nil)
      }
  }

  m.to(immutable.Map)
}
```